# WebSocket: How to receive a message from an already built server using weboscket connection?

Tags: typescript, websocket

I relatively new to work with websocket connections, so please bare with me if my question phrase isn't clear.
I have an already build server (by my team, so I don't know the inside details).
I can connect to that server using `wscat` in `Terminal_1`, then after connecting, and using a command like the following `{"method": "LISTEN", "resource": "test"}` in the same terminal, I can get updates to any messages coming to the server (using another terminal, `Terminal_2`).

The messages to the server are sent using `curl -X POST` command.

The requirement is to write a typescript code that does the same, i.e, connecting to the server and listening to coming messages (from `Terminal_2`, using `curl`)

So far, I could succeed establishing a websocket connection, however, I could't receive updates when messages are sent to the server.

My code is the following:

```
function myWebSocketOpen() {
    const mySocket = new ws("wss://xxx.yyy.com/ws?x=10");
    mySocket.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
        console.log("Websocket is open");
    });

    mySocket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        console.log("Message from server ");
    });
}

myWebSocketOpen();
```

How can I listen to updates coming to the server after establishing the connection?

**Update**

I think the key lies that when I connect using terminal, I send this message after connecting `{"method": "LISTEN", "resource": "test"}`, which I don't know how to configure that using typescript. (I am not sure though).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `wscat` but I'm pretty familiar with websockets and I don't think anyone should be expecting you to set this up without explicit details.

You could try this:

```
mySocket.addEventListener("line", function (event) {
    console.log("Message from server ");
});

mySocket.emit('line', '{"method": "LISTEN", "resource": "test"}' );
```

(I think) That's basically what `wscat` is doing. But again, your team should REALLY be giving you details instead of expecting you to dig through the source code of some package for something like this.